# How do I make this code say "Please hold" and play a custom mp3?

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

This is a conference line that begins when the moderator joins.

It works perfectly except I can't figure out how to make it say "Please hold, you'll be connected shortly." to all callers.

I also want to play a custom mp3 file for the hold music.

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install

// this line loads the library
require_once '/var/www/one/conference/twilio/Twilio/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Twiml;

// Update with your own phone number in E.164 format
$MODERATOR = '+1347999999';

$response = new Twiml;

// Start with a <Dial> verb

$dial = $response->dial();

// If the caller is our MODERATOR, then start the conference when they
// join and end the conference when they leave
if ($_REQUEST['From'] == $MODERATOR) {
$dial->conference('My conference', array(
            'startConferenceOnEnter' => True,
            'endConferenceOnExit' => True,
            'beep' => True,
            'record' => True

            ));

} else {
// Otherwise have the caller join as a regular participant
$dial->conference('My conference', array(
            'startConferenceOnEnter' => False
            ));
}

print $response;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In order to get a message at the start of the call, you need to use the [TwiML `<Say>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) before you use the [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial).

To play custom music before the conference starts, you'll want to use the [`waitUrl` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#attributes-waitUrl) on the [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference) tag. The `waitUrl` is a URL that points at either an MP3 or Wav file or something that returns TwiML which could include multiple [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) or [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) verbs.

Here's an update of your code that includes a message at the start and a `waitUrl` for music (notably, the moderator doesn't need a `waitUrl` as they start the conference):

```
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install

// this line loads the library
require_once '/var/www/one/conference/twilio/Twilio/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Twiml;

// Update with your own phone number in E.164 format
$MODERATOR = '+1347999999';

$response = new Twiml;

// Start with a welcome message
$response->say("Please hold, you'll be connected shortly.");

// Then add the <Dial> verb
$dial = $response->dial();

// If the caller is our MODERATOR, then start the conference when they
// join and end the conference when they leave
if ($_REQUEST['From'] == $MODERATOR) {
$dial->conference('My conference', array(
            'startConferenceOnEnter' => True,
            'endConferenceOnExit' => True,
            'beep' => True,
            'record' => True
            ));

} else {
// Otherwise have the caller join as a regular participant
$dial->conference('My conference', array(
            'startConferenceOnEnter' => False,
            'waitUrl' => 'http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.classical'
            ));
}

print $response;
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thank you @philnash I was putting <say> in the wrong place below dial, the say now works but my custom mp3 waitUrl still doesn't.  I am putting it in the same place as above like this  'waitUrl' => 'https://www.website.com/Vivaldi-Andante.mp3' but it doesnt work.

Comment: Just a thought, maybe my custom waitUrl didn't work because I was on my moderator caller ID - I'll try a different number later.  Thanks again @philnash - just getting the say working is a huge help!

Comment: Ok I tested from my non-moderator phone and I get the desired Vivaldi!  The answer works perfectly.